# C++: Make an array from main() available in another funtion

Tags: c++, arrays, program-entry-point

I am trying to create a C++ program which stores many names linked to a numeric value, and can alter the numeric value when the name is entered. My question is: if I create an array in the main function, can it be accessed from another function? And if so, what should be done for that?

Attaching code (part of it)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> //required as input\output is from\to file
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int name_checker (string input);

int main()
{
int cases;
cin >> cases;
string names[cases]; //this is the array.
int i=0;
while (i<cases)
{
    cin >> names[i];
    i++;
}
}

int name_checker (string input);
{
            //i want the data stored in above array to be availible here. possible?
}
```

Comment: You can pass the array as a parameter...

Comment: You're certainly better off using a `std::vector<std::string> names(cases);`. And change your function signature to `int name_checker (const std::vector<std::string>& input)` (note that there's no semicolon for a function definition!).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : thanks. the semicolon is a typo btw.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible. Pass the array as an argument to the function.

Change the function as -

```
int name_checker (string input[]);
```

And pass the array to the function -

```
name_checker(names);
```

Note: Changing the values in the function will also affect the original values.

Comment: Passing a `std::vector` is simpler and safer.  When passing arrays, the capacity of the array must also be passed.

Comment: Yup, agree, vector is better, to save memory.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using a class.
So you can make the array a field (as πάντα ῥεῖ suggested you should consider using a vector ) and name_check a member function.

Comment: maybe because your suggestion is completely different from the original program.